# WP_Query using meta_query with LIKE doesn't return what it should

Tags: wp-query, meta-query, comparison

I am using this code to get stuff based on my custom field and custom content type.

```
$searchTerm = 'bestafricanvideos';

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'sitemaps',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'cstm_sitemap_url',
            'value'   => $searchTerm,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
    )
);

print_r($args);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

        $video_url = rwmb_meta('cstm_sitemap_url');
        print_r($video_url);

    endwhile;

else : 

    echo "No video URL found";

    exit;

endif;

wp_reset_postdata();

print_r($video_url);
```

And the problem is that nothing is returned.

If I remove the metaquery I get a lot of results.

So, I think the problem is that I have stored the custom meta field in db as an url, for example: `http://bestafricanvideos.com/top10.html` and my search term is `bestafricanvideos` so, maybe the LIKE cannot grab it and only something like this: `http:// bestafricanvideos .com/top10.html` will be grabbed?

Any idea how to fix the meta_query so I can grab stuff that conatain the search term in a longer string (or part of a string)?

Comment: That `LIKE` query will be a wildcard query-- `%searchterm%`-- so it should match any of the strings you provided as samples. Exactly where in the code does is "return nothing"? I assume you've debugged by, for example, checking `var_dump($the_query->request);`?

Comment: Hmm it seems to be something with wordpress escaping the string. E.g. If i put the whole url int othe query the result is this: `'%http://bestafricanvideos.com/videos\\_top\\_10.xml%' )`

Comment: Interesting. I don't see that effect